# MathHelper.Lerp C# (Linear Interpolation)

Tags: c#, xna, linear-interpolation

I'm having a small problem with this function, `MathHelper.Lerp(float f1, float f2, float amount)`. What I'm trying to accomplish is this: I'm having a DataTable in my program with angles and a value correspinding towards this angle value. When you choose an angle not present in the Table I want to use Linear Interpolation to manage this. I want something to replace my first implementation of this which looked like this:

```
else if(angle >= 50 && marklast < 65)
        {
            DataRow row1 = table.Rows.Find(50);
            DataRow row2 = table.Rows.Find(65);
            someVariable = SomeMethod(row1, row2);
        }
```

So now I have a lot of these If statments and would like an other way of doing this with the `MathHelper.Lerp`, problem is I'm having a hard time getting the function, what is amount? And would you modify this in a good way for my implementation?

Comment: On the assumption that there are no supernatural beings in your table, I have edited your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Amount is a value in 0..1 range.

```
if it is 0 lerp return source value, 
if it is 1 lerp return target value, 
if it is a value between 0..1 lerp will return a linear interpolated value between the source and the target values.
```

I'm not sure you want to do...  I think is something like this:

```
Amount = (angle - 50)/(65-50);
InterpolatedValue = MathHelper.Lerp(row1.Value, row2.Value, Amount);
```